# SVG and FIREFOX and transform origin, why not working?

Tags: css, svg

I have this example svg where flower on coffee mug should spin with transform-origin center.

In other browsers it works like champ but in firefox rotates randomly.

Have anybody else have this problem? Is there any easy fixes or im in s**t? :D

Thanks for all the help guys :) !

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="696.667px" height="428.666px" viewBox="0 0 696.667 428.666" enable-background="new 0 0 696.667 428.666"
  xml:space="preserve">

 <style>

  #coffeeFlower {
   -webkit-animation-name: coffeeFlower-animation;
           animation-name: coffeeFlower-animation;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
              animation-duration: 20s;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
              animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-transform-origin: center;
          -ms-transform-origin: center;
              transform-origin: center;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
              animation-timing-function: linear;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes coffeeFlower-animation {
      0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);}
      100%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);transform: rotate(360deg);}
  }

  @keyframes coffeeFlower-animation {
      0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);}
      100%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);transform: rotate(360deg);}
  }

 </style>


<g>
 <g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <path fill="#FF00CD" d="M402.577,58.794c135.259-11.36,221.089,81.12,232.3,157.827
     c9.135,62.505-17.688,206.188-222.337,207.712c-204.65,1.523-207.344-171.682-207.243-205.123
     C205.399,185.767,241.826,72.295,402.577,58.794z"/>
    <path fill="#9B009B" d="M400.396,115.509c45.462-1.239,113.712-17.373,126.306-46.262
     c12.594-28.891-57.617-51.955-128.93-50.012c-71.313,1.944-114.239,30.769-113.681,51.271
     C284.65,91.009,324.625,117.573,400.396,115.509"/>
    <path fill="#FF00CD" d="M394.548,3.81c11.438-1.887,25.438,1.115,26.92,12.675c1.482,11.56-11.712,13.737-16.993,14.609
     c-8.362,1.38-19.837-0.618-24.626-8.452C373.64,12.485,386.072,5.208,394.548,3.81z"/>
    <path fill="#FF00CD" d="M227.215,307.564c0,0-50.859-0.397-61.369-25.981s-4.278-58.761-19.869-74.393
     c-15.591-15.633-22.577-10.09-23.638-16.306s8.574-12.723,17.439-14.749c8.866-2.025,25.924,1.971,33.274,9.799
     s19.619,32.472,35.664,32.034c16.045-0.437,29.351,29.53,30.704,46.443S227.215,307.564,227.215,307.564z"/>
    <path fill="#FF00CD" d="M600.25,149.313c0,0,38.16-7.285,68.258,16.873c30.097,24.158,30.396,67.861,11.344,88.898
     c-12.95,14.299-49.288,24.537-49.288,24.537l0.859-33.922c0,0,26.791,1.053,30.665-20.462
     c3.874-21.516-2.754-35.608-13.646-42.448s-30.479-5.414-30.479-5.414l-17.738-28.955"/>
    <path fill="#9B009B" d="M141.682,180.544c-4.545,0.125-15.033,4.871-14.068,7.521s13.493,4.093,22.383,2.958
     c8.89-1.134,14.141-4.846,9.611-7.398C155.078,181.071,147.922,180.374,141.682,180.544z"/>
   </g>
   <path id="coffeeFlower" fill="#CDFF31" d="M436.924,236.235c0,0,35.948-25.799,9.224-56.801c-18.286-21.213-37.782-3.01-41.195,19.973
    c-3.413,22.982,1.027,37.672,1.027,37.672s-6.398-37.141-37.238-32.453s-51.193,48.327-26.609,61.121s50.694,5.351,50.694,5.351
    s-36.616,17.155-30.538,42.571c6.079,25.416,40.803,15.045,48.435-1.32c7.633-16.365,7.633-16.365,7.633-16.365
    s12.673,36.734,36.975,30.996c24.302-5.738,26.406-27.338,19.312-40.608s-30.296-24.757-30.296-24.757s43.457,13.627,60.36-8.377
    c16.904-22.003-5.356-48.324-24.119-45.121C461.827,211.321,436.924,236.235,436.924,236.235z"/>
   <path fill="#00FFFF" d="M411.361,236.933c0,0-17.852,11.93-10.048,26.528c7.803,14.598,25.147,8.739,32.29-0.88
    C440.746,252.962,436.484,220.091,411.361,236.933z"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path fill="#FF00CD" d="M13.559,335.13c0,0,12.598-5.814,45.546-6.783c32.948-0.97,65.896,3.876,72.68,13.566
    c6.784,9.69-4.845,82.37-62.989,82.37S2.899,358.387,3.869,350.634C4.838,342.882,4.838,338.036,13.559,335.13z"/>
   <path fill="#FF9B00" d="M13.559,343.851c-3.876,14.536,16.474,15.506,51.36,16.475s59.113-5.814,60.082-11.629
    c0.969-5.814-27.025-9.889-41.67-10.66C64.919,337.067,15.325,337.229,13.559,343.851z"/>
   <path fill="#FF00CD" d="M129.847,358.387c0,0,18.412,6.784,21.319,19.382s0,24.227-10.66,29.071c-10.66,4.846-31.01,0-31.01,0
    l6.783-14.536c0,0,16.474,9.691,22.289,0c5.814-9.69-10.66-22.288-10.66-22.288L129.847,358.387z"/>
  </g>
  <path id="kohviJuga" fill="#FF9B00" d="M135.634,190.937c0,0,3.591,1.055,10.046,0.43c6.455-0.627,9.624-1.438,9.624-1.438
   s-4.441-26.975-10.921-40.859c-13.567-29.071-49.422-27.133-60.082-2.906c-7.364,16.735-20.35,202.533-20.35,202.533h19.381
   c0,0,6.228-180,13.567-192.844c7.752-13.566,31.01-17.442,35.855,10.66C134.433,176.251,135.634,190.937,135.634,190.937z"/>
 </g>
 <path fill="#FF9B00" d="M55.229,315.748c0,0-5.814-30.04-16.474-25.195S55.229,315.748,55.229,315.748z"/>
 <path fill="#FF9B00" d="M91.084,322.532c0,0,0.969-10.66,6.784-9.691S91.084,322.532,91.084,322.532z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Example code here: https://codepen.io/mrmagnus/pen/jmOVPq

Comment: In Internet Explorer 11, it doesn't rotate at all. Neither it does in Edge 38.

Comment: IE does not support CSS transforms on SVG elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has the correct behaviour according to the spec.  For SVG elements "transform-origin: center" means the centre of the SVG.  Chrome has implemented an older version of the spec and is now technically wrong.

In the future, you'll be able to set the box used to calculate percentage (center = 50%) origin values, with the `transform-box` property.

Until then, if you want compatibility between browsers, you'll need to use absolute coordinates.

```
transform-origin: 421px 250px;
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="696.667px" height="428.666px" viewBox="0 0 696.667 428.666" enable-background="new 0 0 696.667 428.666"
  xml:space="preserve">

 <style>

  #coffeeFlower {
   -webkit-animation-name: coffeeFlower-animation;
           animation-name: coffeeFlower-animation;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
              animation-duration: 20s;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
              animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 421px 250px;
          -ms-transform-origin: 421px 250px;
              transform-origin: 421px 250px;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
              animation-timing-function: linear;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes coffeeFlower-animation {
      0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);}
      100%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);transform: rotate(360deg);}
  }

  @keyframes coffeeFlower-animation {
      0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);}
      100%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);transform: rotate(360deg);}
  }

 </style>


<g>
 <g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <path fill="#FF00CD" d="M402.577,58.794c135.259-11.36,221.089,81.12,232.3,157.827
     c9.135,62.505-17.688,206.188-222.337,207.712c-204.65,1.523-207.344-171.682-207.243-205.123
     C205.399,185.767,241.826,72.295,402.577,58.794z"/>
    <path fill="#9B009B" d="M400.396,115.509c45.462-1.239,113.712-17.373,126.306-46.262
     c12.594-28.891-57.617-51.955-128.93-50.012c-71.313,1.944-114.239,30.769-113.681,51.271
     C284.65,91.009,324.625,117.573,400.396,115.509"/>
    <path fill="#FF00CD" d="M394.548,3.81c11.438-1.887,25.438,1.115,26.92,12.675c1.482,11.56-11.712,13.737-16.993,14.609
     c-8.362,1.38-19.837-0.618-24.626-8.452C373.64,12.485,386.072,5.208,394.548,3.81z"/>
    <path fill="#FF00CD" d="M227.215,307.564c0,0-50.859-0.397-61.369-25.981s-4.278-58.761-19.869-74.393
     c-15.591-15.633-22.577-10.09-23.638-16.306s8.574-12.723,17.439-14.749c8.866-2.025,25.924,1.971,33.274,9.799
     s19.619,32.472,35.664,32.034c16.045-0.437,29.351,29.53,30.704,46.443S227.215,307.564,227.215,307.564z"/>
    <path fill="#FF00CD" d="M600.25,149.313c0,0,38.16-7.285,68.258,16.873c30.097,24.158,30.396,67.861,11.344,88.898
     c-12.95,14.299-49.288,24.537-49.288,24.537l0.859-33.922c0,0,26.791,1.053,30.665-20.462
     c3.874-21.516-2.754-35.608-13.646-42.448s-30.479-5.414-30.479-5.414l-17.738-28.955"/>
    <path fill="#9B009B" d="M141.682,180.544c-4.545,0.125-15.033,4.871-14.068,7.521s13.493,4.093,22.383,2.958
     c8.89-1.134,14.141-4.846,9.611-7.398C155.078,181.071,147.922,180.374,141.682,180.544z"/>
   </g>
   <path id="coffeeFlower" fill="#CDFF31" d="M436.924,236.235c0,0,35.948-25.799,9.224-56.801c-18.286-21.213-37.782-3.01-41.195,19.973
    c-3.413,22.982,1.027,37.672,1.027,37.672s-6.398-37.141-37.238-32.453s-51.193,48.327-26.609,61.121s50.694,5.351,50.694,5.351
    s-36.616,17.155-30.538,42.571c6.079,25.416,40.803,15.045,48.435-1.32c7.633-16.365,7.633-16.365,7.633-16.365
    s12.673,36.734,36.975,30.996c24.302-5.738,26.406-27.338,19.312-40.608s-30.296-24.757-30.296-24.757s43.457,13.627,60.36-8.377
    c16.904-22.003-5.356-48.324-24.119-45.121C461.827,211.321,436.924,236.235,436.924,236.235z"/>
   <path fill="#00FFFF" d="M411.361,236.933c0,0-17.852,11.93-10.048,26.528c7.803,14.598,25.147,8.739,32.29-0.88
    C440.746,252.962,436.484,220.091,411.361,236.933z"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path fill="#FF00CD" d="M13.559,335.13c0,0,12.598-5.814,45.546-6.783c32.948-0.97,65.896,3.876,72.68,13.566
    c6.784,9.69-4.845,82.37-62.989,82.37S2.899,358.387,3.869,350.634C4.838,342.882,4.838,338.036,13.559,335.13z"/>
   <path fill="#FF9B00" d="M13.559,343.851c-3.876,14.536,16.474,15.506,51.36,16.475s59.113-5.814,60.082-11.629
    c0.969-5.814-27.025-9.889-41.67-10.66C64.919,337.067,15.325,337.229,13.559,343.851z"/>
   <path fill="#FF00CD" d="M129.847,358.387c0,0,18.412,6.784,21.319,19.382s0,24.227-10.66,29.071c-10.66,4.846-31.01,0-31.01,0
    l6.783-14.536c0,0,16.474,9.691,22.289,0c5.814-9.69-10.66-22.288-10.66-22.288L129.847,358.387z"/>
  </g>
  <path id="kohviJuga" fill="#FF9B00" d="M135.634,190.937c0,0,3.591,1.055,10.046,0.43c6.455-0.627,9.624-1.438,9.624-1.438
   s-4.441-26.975-10.921-40.859c-13.567-29.071-49.422-27.133-60.082-2.906c-7.364,16.735-20.35,202.533-20.35,202.533h19.381
   c0,0,6.228-180,13.567-192.844c7.752-13.566,31.01-17.442,35.855,10.66C134.433,176.251,135.634,190.937,135.634,190.937z"/>
 </g>
 <path fill="#FF9B00" d="M55.229,315.748c0,0-5.814-30.04-16.474-25.195S55.229,315.748,55.229,315.748z"/>
 <path fill="#FF9B00" d="M91.084,322.532c0,0,0.969-10.66,6.784-9.691S91.084,322.532,91.084,322.532z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Google Chrome has a bugguy interpretation of the CSS style `transform-origin: center`.

But you can get rid of it and have the same behaviour on both browsers using this technique :

```
  <g transform="translate(411,250)">
    <g id="coffeeFlower">
      <path transform="translate(-420,-250)"
            d="...your yellow flower..."/>
    </g>
  </g>
```

The rotation is always computed on (0,0), but you use the trick of the double translation.

You just have to fine tune the translations and it will work like a charm (as you say).

See it in action : https://jsfiddle.net/hvngvz3y/2/

Comment: how you chose those translate cordinates?
`<g transform="translate(411,250)">
    <g id="coffeeFlower">
      <path transform="translate(-420,-250)"
            d="...your yellow flower..."/>
    </g>
  </g>`

Comment: I looked roughly at the `coffeeFlower`coordinates and tried to guess the center.